# jQuery, .net and .on(click) fails after ajax event

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

i'm breaking my head on this. I got an **aspx** page with some **html** and **asp controls** for a mobile site on **jQuery mobile**. There is some jQuery in an external file that goes like this:

```
$(window).load(function () {

$('#chktlnao').on('click', function(){
    alert('chktlnao click');// debug
    //other things
});

});
```

This works fine when the page loads, it does some changes on some radio & checkbox buttons.

The problem comes when at the top of this page, the user hits another radio buttons to change via ajax some infos in the page. Then, the radio/checkboxes (like `#chktlnao`) stop working, even if they stay on the page with no modifications.

The top radio buttons are `asp:RadioButton`s and within the vb code there is something like this that links to them: `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="optPE" EventName="CheckedChanged" />`

The .net part isn't handled by me.
The site runs with jQuery 1.8.2 and jQuery mobile 1.2.0.

I've already tried many things like:

on `window.load` and `document.ready`:

```
$(document).on("click", "#chktlnao", function(){ ... });

$("body").on("click", "#chktlnao", function(event){ ... });
```

I'm pretty sure i'm missing something with jQuery mobile but can't seem to spot it. I also know that `live` is deprecated, so the solution should be within the `on` method.

Comment: What abt `change` instead of `click`?

Comment: Are you sure there's no duplicated id's?

Comment: @passionateCoder no this does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: @Omar yep i've check again, no duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was failing due to some vb.net code and it's been decided to use a vb based solution rather than javscript.
Thanks for the help guys.